# Locate all distinct values in nested JSON array

Tags: json, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Background:

I wish to locate all the distinct values for my "state" key within this nested array

```
      {
          "id": "123"
          "feedback" : {
             "Features" : [
                              {
                                "state":"new"
                              }
        

                          ]
     }
```

This is what I have tried to do:

Since this is a nested document. My query looks like this:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT c.feedback.Features  FROM c 
   WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.feedback.Features, {state}, true)
```

I am looking through the documentation and do not see this case for finding distinct values within a nested array. I will continue to research.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.state FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features
```

if you just need value of state,you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE d.state FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: This works! Thank you @stevezhao. How do you know what to label the containers (d,c ??) I am wondering could you offer suggestion on my latest question? I am having a roadblock